# Audio streamed from assembly resource is fast, loud and distorted

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio, stream, .net-assembly

I'm trying to load an AudioClip (to be played by an AudioSource) from an assembly resource. However with my current setup, the audio is very loud, extremely distorted and plays about twice as fast. It's a .wav file that's included as a resource in a managed assembly. Anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong? (I've matched the frequency and channels)

```
private static AudioClip LoadAudioClip()
{
    // Try loading from resources first.
    AudioClip audioClip = Resources.Load<AudioClip>(AudioClipResourceFolder + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(EmbeddedChime.FileName));

    if (audioClip == null)
    {
        // Nothing found in resources, load from library manifest instead.
        try
        {
            using (Stream stream = GetResourceStream(EmbeddedChime.FileName))
            {
                float[] buffer = GetAudioBuffer(stream);
                audioClip = AudioClip.Create("Chime", buffer.Length, 2, 44100, true, false);
                if (!audioClip.SetData(buffer, 0))
                {
                    throw new NotSupportedException(EmbeddedChime.FileName);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            AMDebug.LogError($"Failed to load {EmbeddedChime.FileName} from Assembly library manifest: " + e.Message);
        }
    }

    return audioClip;
}

private static float[] GetAudioBuffer(Stream stream)
{
    byte[] buffer = GetResourceBuffer(stream);
    
    float[] floatBuffer = new float[buffer.Length / 4];
    for (int i = 0; i < floatBuffer.Length; i++) 
    {
        if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
        {
            Array.Reverse(buffer, i * 4, 4);
        }

        floatBuffer[i] = BitConverter.ToSingle(buffer, i*4) / 0x80000000;
    }

    return floatBuffer;
}

private static byte[] GetResourceBuffer(Stream stream)
{
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[stream.Length];
    stream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)stream.Length);
    return buffer;
}

private static Stream GetResourceStream(string resourceName)
{
    return AudioMobAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName);
}
```

Comment: Please note that the [tag:assembly] tag is meant for questions about assembly language. not .NET assemblies.  I'm removing it.

Comment: @NateEldredge sorry and thankyou

Comment: @NateEldredge: There's a [.net-assembly] tag; we asm tag followers normally edit [assembly] into that on questions like this, instead of removing it.  (There's also an [assemblies] tag which should probably just be a synonym; I never tag it.)